# Centralizar div dentro de scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Possuo uma div pai que tem a scroll habilitada e um limite de width, debaixo dela possuo outra div com conteúdo.

Meu desejo é centralizar esse conteúdo em relação a div pai de forma que o conteúdo fique centralizado, observem:

```
<div class="scroll">
<div class="content">
00000000000000000111000000000000000000
</div>
</div>

.scroll {
  overflow:auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:black;
}
.content {
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1unhL34/

Dessa forma só aparecem os `0` mas da forma centralizada apareceria os `1` também.

Existem alguma artimanha em CSS ou jQuery/JavaScript para realizar tal?

Comment: Uma forma interessante de centralizar div's em relação a outras é usando flexbox:
[http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-centralizar-divs-em-html-e-css/37568?utm_source=browser&utm_medium=push_notification&utm_campaign=PushCrew_notification_1483020272&pushcrew_powered](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-centralizar-divs-em-html-e-css/37568?utm_source=browser&utm_medium=push_notification&utm_campaign=PushCrew_notification_1483020272&pushcrew_powered)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar **jQuery** ou **JS** puro para fazer isso.
No caso eu usei **jQuery** para pegar o tamanho do elemento `.content`.

Daí fiz uma divisão por 2 para chegar na metade da `div.srcoll`.

O maior problema é que temos que descontar o tamanho das setinhas da direita e esquerda. Eu chutei uns `25px` para cada, logo `50px`.

E depois usei a função `scrollLeft();`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollMiddle = ($('.content').width() / 2) - 50;
  $('.scroll').scrollLeft(scrollMiddle);
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.content {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="content">
    0000000000000000011100000000000000000
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue posicionar o scroll **exatamente** ao meio subtraindo a largura da div maior pela menor e dividindo por 2.

Para isso pode usar o método JavaScript `.scrollTo()` alterando apenas o primeiro parâmetro (eixo `X`) e deixando o segundo parâmetro (eixo `Y`) com o valor `0`, já que só deseja mover o scroll na horizontal (eixo `X`):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var scrl = document.querySelector(".scroll"); // pega a div de classe .scroll
   var scrlWidth = scrl.offsetWidth; // pega a largura a div de classe .scroll
   var cont = document.querySelector(".content").offsetWidth; // pega a largura da div de classe .content
   scrl.scrollTo( (cont-scrlWidth)/2, 0 ); // move o scroll apenas na horizontal
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  overflow:auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:black;
}
.content {
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
   <div class="content">
      00000000000000000111000000000000000000
   </div>
</div>
```

Se desejar usar jQuery, a lógica é a mesma, mudando apenas a sintaxe:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var scrl = $(".scroll"); // pega a div de classe .scroll
   var scrlWidth = scrl.width(); // pega a largura a div de classe .scroll
   var cont = $(".content").width(); // pega a largura da div de classe .content
   scrl.scrollLeft((cont-scrlWidth)/2); // move o scroll apenas na horizontal
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  overflow:auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:black;
}
.content {
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
   <div class="content">
      00000000000000000111000000000000000000
   </div>
</div>
```

> Note que nos exemplos o `111` não aparece exatamente ao meio porque tem
>   1 zero a mais à direita do que à esquerda, mas o scroll está
>   centralizado.